# No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '

Tags: typescript

I was working on my first firebase typescript function project

I have following code snippet.

```
const files = {
    status: './src/api/status.f.js',
    invite: './src/api/invite.f.js',
    user: './src/api/user.f.js',
    auth: './src/api/auth.f.js',
    social: './src/api/social.f.js'
}

for (let file in files)
    if (files.hasOwnProperty(file)) {
        // Setting function name equivalent to the file name
        if (!process.env.FUNCTION_NAME || process.env.FUNCTION_NAME === file) {
            const ApiClass = require(files[file])
            const app = new ApiClass(context)
            exports[file] = app.handler
        }
    }
```

In this, at this line i am getting following error `const ApiClass = require(files[file])`

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type
>   'string' can't be used to index type '{ status: string; invite:
>   string; user: string; auth: string; social: string; }'.   No index
>   signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{
>   status: string; invite: string; user: string; auth: string; social:
>   string; }'

**Primary Question:** Can someone help me figure out what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The type error is shown because you turned on `"noImplicitAny": true` in tsconfig.

If you like to keep `"noImplicitAny": true`, then there're 2 fixes to your problem, choose either one.

1. `const ApiClass = require(files[file as keyof typeof files])`
2. `const files: { [key: string]: string } = { ... }`

---

After some digging, I think the optimal way is to augment the `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()` method's signature.

```js
// somewhere in your project, write:

interface Object {
  hasOwnProperty<T>(this: T, v: any): v is keyof T
}
```

This way `.hasOwnProperty` acts as a type guard that narrows down type of `file` to be `keyof typeof files` automatically.

Comment: There's another cool way of typing objects in TypeScript, by the way:

`const myObj: Record<string, number | RegExp> = {...};`

Answer (score 0):

***Option 1***

1. Cast to `any`
2. Cast to `keyof typeof`

**Example:**

```
const options = { '-a': 'Alpha', '-o': 'Omega' }
let strOptions = 'Options are:'

for (const k in options) {
  const kAny: any = k
  const key: (keyof typeof options) = kAny

  strOptions += `\n${ key } => ${ options[ key ] }`
}
```

***Option 2:***

1. Use a map

```
const options = new Map([
  ['-a', 'Alpha'],
  ['-o', 'Omega'],
])

let strOptions = 'Options are:'

options.forEach((v, k) => {
  strOptions += `\n${ k } => ${ v }`
})
```