# Property 'country' does not exist on type 'never' and type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6, types

The property I am trying to make indexable is `title[0]` and it is a string.

I am getting this error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'.ts(7053)
```

When I do this:

```js
        const letter = title[0];
        acc[letter] = acc[letter] || { id: i++, letter, country: [] };
        acc[letter].country.push({ title, content: [...content] });
```

And this other error:

```
Property 'country' does not exist on type 'never'.ts(2339)
```

When I do this:

```js
        const letter = title[0] as keyof typeof acc;
        acc[letter] = acc[letter] || { id: i++, letter, country: [] };
        // This is the line that throws the error
        acc[letter].country.push({ title, content: [...content] });
```

This is the whole function:

```js
const sortBrands = (): NewBrandInterface[] => {
    let i = 1;
    const result: NewBrandInterface[] = Object.values(
      globalBrands.reduce((acc, { title, content }) => {
        const letter = title[0] as keyof typeof acc;

        acc[letter] = acc[letter] || { id: i++, letter, country: [] };
        acc[letter].country.push({ title, content: [...content] });

        return acc;
      }, {}));

    return mergeObjectsInUnique(result, 'letter');
  };
```

And these are my interfaces:

```js
interface WithURL extends VariousContent {
  url: string;
}

interface Country {
  title: string;
  content: WithURL[];
}

interface NewBrandInterface {
  id: number;
  letter: string;
  country: Country[];
}
```

Comment: You get the error at compile time right?

Comment: Hey @EmanueleScarabattoli as soon as I do any of those things the IDE marks it as an error.

Comment: The second error cause: if `letter` can only be `id`, `letter`, `country`, then `acc[letter]` will always be available because, presumably, `acc` is typed properly. So the statement `acc[letter] = acc[letter]` attempts to set  `acc.letter` equal to the string `letter`. Then you attempt to access the `country` property like this: `acc.letter.country` - country doesn't exist.

Comment: @RandyCasburn any solutions?

Comment: I suppose it starts with understanding the data structures you are dealing with. There is not enough information in the question to determine that as an outsider. Your assignments are all so confused, you've just started discovering problems in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the main point is that your accumulator does not have a type so the `acc` variable it is not supposed to have a `country` property at compile time.

Why you get `never`? Because of this: https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/typescript/typescript-never

First of all you need to give it type in this way:

```
globalBrands.reduce<NewBrandInterface>(...)
```

Then you will get an error since `{}`, the default value, does not have all the props expected (`id`, `letter`, `country`), so you have two options:

1. make these properties as optional
2. initialize the `acc` with all the properties needed

Comment: Is is `globalBrands.reduce<NewBrandInterface>(...)` or `globalBrands.reduce<NewBrandInterface[]>(...)`? I made all of the properties optional and I am getting this now: `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'NewBrandInterface'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'NewBrandInterface'.ts(7053)`

Comment: In this case maybe this can be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/58812294/8534482

Comment: How can I apply that to my case?

Comment: Not sure but... what happens  if you do this: `const letter: "id" | "letter" | "country"`?

Comment: `Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"id" | "letter" | "country"'.ts(2322)`